# Unfailing Javascript Image Preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, google-chrome, image-preloader

I have the following code that presents the user with a preview of the image they're trying to upload and works really well in FF:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = $('#imageUploader').get(0).files[0].getAsDataURL();
```

The problem is, `getAsDataURL()` only works in FF. Is there something similar/a workaround for this kind of functionality in Chrome (specifically)?

Comment: pretty much. You will need to use gears, flash, or java. In IE6 you can just get the value of the file upload and use "file:///..." to display the preview, But I think they 86'd that in ie7.

Comment: i don't believe you. someone must know of a non-flash way.

Comment: Isn't the `.get()` method supposed to load data from the server with a GET request? (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) Maybe you meant `.eq()`?

Comment: There is not such a way. The standard process is stalled, when it is confirmed, the Firefox team will update their API (which they are now discouraging the public to use, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File) to conform to it, and the Webkit one will implement it

Comment: I simply refuse to believe that the only way to achieve this effect is with flash or an applet. SOMEONE has to know of a way. Especially with all the web8 effects out there

Comment: you are stubborn and kinda grumpy.

Comment: it's these damn kids always on my lawn

Answer (score 2):

If the browser doesn't support `getAsDataURL` you could make sure that the file input is instead using Gears' [openFiles](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_desktop.html) (scroll down) to read a file selected by the user.
Google ain't working on Gears anymore, but it will work in Chrome, at least until `getAsDataURL()` gets implemented.

**EDIT:** Changed answer to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

IE does not yet support the File API. Anyhow, you need to use a FileReader to read a file. Also, the file is not its file name (your variable naming is a little ambiguous).

```
file = fileObj.files[0];
var fr = new FileReader;
fr.onloadend = changeimg;
fr.readAsDataURL(file)
```

Comment: But, eh, the question isn't about IE, it's about Chrome. (The question is also really old - that code should work in the current version of Chrome).